# What carriers can utilize my unlocked AT&T iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, unlock, att

What carriers can utilize my network unlocked AT&T iPhone 5? I just unlocked it by submitting the request to AT&T and restoring it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the back of your phone you will find a 5 character model number, Specifically the letter A followed by 4 digits.

You stated you have an iPhone 5, and it was original to the AT&T network you likely have model A1428 which will work in the USA on

```
    Aio
    Alaska Communications
    AT&T
    Family Mobile
    GCI
    Net 10
    Straight Talk
    T-Mobile
    Union Wireless
```

If your model number is different or you will be outside the USA, then use [this table](https://www.apple.com/iphone/LTE/) on the Apple website to look up your specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Your iPhone should work with any GSM carrier, which includes ATT, T-Mobile, and just about all other companies that use this technology. Companies that won't work are Sprint and Verizon or anyone who uses CDMA instead of GSM.